# How to make an automated installation package from compiling?

Tags: compiling, software-installation, bittorrent, bitcoin

In this scenario I am looking at [Twister](http://twister.net.co/?page_id=23) and at the moment you can only compile Twister. How would one start making this installation process automaticly?

Twister is the fully decentralized P2P microblogging platform leveraging from the free software implementations of Bitcoin and BitTorrent protocols.